# Rails Add to group button using 3 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is probably really simple, but I've been racking my brain for a couple of days and can't figure it out!I'm new to rails so any pointing in the right direction would be much appreciated!
I have 3 models: collective, group_membership & user. I want the user to be able to join a collective, by pushing a button on the collective index & show pages. 
Do I need a controller for the group_membership? 
I thought of using a form for which inherits the attributes of the collective_id & user_id as hidden fields, with the join button as the form submit, but I couldn't figure it out. If you need to know anything else, let me know!

Here's an extract of what I have.

**Models**

```
class Collective < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :group_memberships


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :group_memberships
end


class GroupMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :collective

  validates_uniqueness_of :collective_id, :message => "can be only joined once", :scope => 'user_id'
end

 class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
   validates :user_name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 20 }

   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   has_many :collectives, :through => :group_memberships
   has_many :group_memberships
end
```

**Collective Controller**

```
 class CollectivesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_collective, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def index
   @collectives = Collective.all

 end

 def show

   @users_group = @collective.users
 end

 def new
   @collective = Collective.new
 end

 def create
   @collective = Collective.new(collective_params)
   @collective.users << current_user

  respond_to do |format|
    if @collective.save
    format.html { redirect_to @collective, notice: 'Collective was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @collective }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @collective.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

  private

def set_collective
  @collective = Collective.find(params[:id])
end


def collective_params
  params.require(:collective).permit(:collectivename, :collectivedescription, :createdby)
end
```

Index extract:

```
  <tbody>
   <% @collectives.each do |collective| %>
   <tr>
    <td><%= collective.collectivename %></td>
    <td><%= collective.collectivedescription %></td>
    <td><%= collective.createdby %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', collective %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_collective_path(collective) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', collective, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
 **Here;s where I'd like to put the join button**
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new route `join` for collectives members in your config/routes.rb

```
resources :collectives do
  member do
    post 'join'
  end
end
```

In your collective_controllers.rb you'd have a new action

```
before_action :set_collective, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :join]

def join
  @collective.users << current_user
  @collective.save
  redirect_to collectives_path
end
```

And in your view...

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', collective, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
<% unless collective.users.include? current_user %>
  <td><%= link_to 'Join', join_collective_path(collective), method: :post %></td>
<% end %>
```